# Flutter: Async Await Function Not Waiting

Tags: flutter, image, dart, asynchronous, async-await

I am doing some image processing and building in my app using the `Image` package. In this case, I am building a `LinearProgressIndicator` widget that is then converted into an image file, that is then merged into a larger image later on. However, the functions to build and take the image of the progress indicator widget isn't being waited on and the following error is observed

```
FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '/Users//Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices//data/Containers/Data/Application//Library/Caches/bar.png' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
```

However, the progress indicator file is being created (I can see the cache), and then if I rerunning the image processing it works just fine (because now the file is there). However, I need it work on the first time. Here is what I have for image processing

```
import 'package:image/image.dart' as ui;

Future<File> instagramChalShare(BuildContext context, double progress) async {
   //this is where it does not appear the progressBarPathFunct is being waited on
   final testFile = await progressBarPathFunct(context, progress);
    ui.Image tester = ui.decodeImage(testFile.readAsBytesSync());
    //image is then resized
    ui.Image progressResized = ui.Image(600, 90);
    ui.drawImage(progressResized, tester);

   //now progress bar is merged into larger image
   final mergedImage = ui.Image(width, height);
   ui.copyInto(mergedImage, progressResized, blend: true);

   List<int> imageFile = ui.encodePng(mergedImage);
   final imageFilePath = await File('${(await getTemporaryDirectory()).path}/temp.png').create();
    print('picture finished $imageFilePath');
    return imageFilePath.writeAsBytes(imageFile);
}
```

Here is the function to build the `LinearProgressIndictor`, convert it to an image, and create a file where the image is held.

```
  Future<File> progressBarPathFunct(BuildContext context, double progress) async {
    final progressFile = File('${(await getTemporaryDirectory()).path}/bar.png');
    var indicator = LinearPercentIndicator(
      percent: progress > 1.0 ? 1.0 : progress,
      width: context.size.width,
      lineHeight: 13,
      ),
      barRadius: Radius.circular(20),
    );
    screenshotController.captureFromWidget(
      InheritedTheme.captureAll(context, Material(child: indicator)),
    ).then((capturedProgress) async {
      await progressFile.create(recursive: true);
      await progressFile.writeAsBytes(capturedProgress);
    });
    print('progress bar path from functions ${progressFile.path}');
    return progressFile;
  }
```

This function is working, but it seems the top one creating the merged Image file is not waiting for this function to finish before attempting to complete.

### Edit

I am following the example from the `screenshot` [package](https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot/example) to generate an image of a widget that is not on the screen.

Comment: There seem to be an exception occuring inside progressBarPathFunct(context, progress). This is why await is not happening. Can you add a try{ }catch(e){ } block inside that method?

Comment: Why is `progressBarPathFunct` using `.then()`?  `progressBarPathFunct` returns `progressFile` without waiting for `screenshotController.captureFromWidget` to complete.  I *strongly* recommend enabling the [`unawaited_future`s lint](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/unawaited_futures.html) to help you catch such mistakes.

Comment: @jamesdlin thanks for your reply. I am following the example in the `screenshot` package to create an image of a widget that is no on screen. Here is the link: https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot/example. I am new to dart, so I am not 100% sure how to use the `unawaited` in this example.

Comment: Update, @jamesdlin that worked! I just needed to add `await` in from of `screenshotController.captureFromWidget`. Thank you for your help!